# Variable initialization in for loop

Tags: c

I had such a question:What is the difference between

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Does this influence memory and time?

Comment: One difference: After the loop, `i` no longer exist.

Comment: No but it influences the scope of the variable i. So if for example you had an outer scope that needed to know how many iterations were made (assuming you may have a break in the loop) then you could use i from that outer scope after the loop. but other than that. no significant difference.

Comment: `{ int i; for(i = 0; i < n; i++) statement }` is exactly semantically equivalent to `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) statement `.

Comment: The other difference is that the first will work with very old compilers, but the second form requires conformance to a newer standard.  (But "newer" here is still decades old)

Comment: "Does this influence memory and time?" --> Even if it did effect a difference, that difference would be linear or constant and not [productive of _your_ time  97% of time,](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)  IWOs, it _may_ affect memory and time, but not significantly, if at all.

Comment: In the second snippet you could have another distinct `int i;` outside of that loop, which would be shadowed by the `i` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.2.1 2 says:

> For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is *visible* (i.e., can be used) only within a region of program text called its *scope*…

6.2.1 4 says:

> Every other identifier [paragraph 3 discussed labels] has scope determined by the placement of its declaration (in a declarator or type specifier)… If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has *block scope*, which terminates at the end of the associated block…

Which portions of C source code form blocks is stated individually in several places.

6.8.2 1:

> A *compound statement* [source code inside `{` and `}`] is a block.

6.8.4 3:

> A *selection statement* [`if`, `if … else`, and `switch`] is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its enclosing block. Each associated substatement is also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the selection statement.

6.8.5 5:

> An iteration statement [`while`, `do … while`, and `for`] is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its enclosing block. The loop body is also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement.

Thus `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` declares an `i` whose scope is limited to the `for` statement. This `i` cannot be used after the `for` statement.

In contrast, the `int i;` before the `for` statement declares an `i` that can be used throughout the block it is in, which is the `{ … }` that it is enclosed in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have written this code in the main function,

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

In the case above, `i` is a local variable of the main function. If the value of `i` is updated in the loop it will remain updated even after the loop ends. `i` is not destroyed after the for loop. This is useful in some programs where you need the value of `i` after the loop for later use.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

In the case above, `i` is a local variable of the for loop. `i` will be destroyed once the loop is over.